# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings() - Gradle links same class twice for Mockito jar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have configured the following dependencies in the build.gradle file.

```
testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19"
```

And when running the tests getting the following error stack trace.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:81)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:69)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:56)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:289)
```

And I've tried to debug it. Found something weird in the IntelliJ linked jar files. Almost most of the classes in the Mockito jar displayed twice.

[image]

Refreshing gradle dependencies or cache clear both did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After so many days, I figured out that the issue is with the mockito jar version mismatch.
Changing the version from mockito-all to mockito-core build.gradle to

```
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.24.0"
    testCompile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: "org.mockito", module: "mockito-all"
    }
```

fixed my problem.

Thanks